# How can I call (use ACTION_CALL) in fore ground service?

Tags: android, android-developer-api

How can I call (use ACTION_CALL) in fore ground service, it works completely fine when app is opened but not in background

```
  new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
      public void run() {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
          intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9325979573" ));
          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
          startActivity(intent);
      }
  });
}
```

i have given permission but yet... idk what to do...

Answer (score 0):

On modern Android you cannot launch an activity from a background.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts.  Notice that for the purposes of starting activities, foreground services do NOT count as in the foreground, they're still counted as in the background, as per that documentation.